# JS/Jquery default function paramater not working in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I want to write this function in jquery like this

```
function hello(a = ''){
  if(a != '') alert("hello");
}
```

My jquery code like this

```
var hello = function(a = ''){
  if(a != '') alert("hello");
}
```

Following functions works fine in desktop browsers and android chrome browser but not working in androd native browser and give me following errors.

```
E/browser (26360): Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =:122
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type in argument, if no paramater were passing, it will returned undefined :

```
var hello = function( myVal ){
  // or you can set it defaut value by using
  // if ( !myVal ) myVal = 'bla bla';
  if(myVal) alert("hello");
}
```

What you used is called the `default function paramater` which is the new features of EcmaScript 2015. And not all the platform support it. You can check on this [link](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

`var` keyword is invalid in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to declare the variable outside of the function call and pass it is an argument. This way you will be able to pass in any value into the function. or you can use the arguments object in the function - this snippet gives two version of the function and console.logs the result.:

```js
   hello('');
   hello2('')

  function hello(text){
      if(text == '') console.log("hello");
    }

  function hello2(){
     if(arguments[0] == '') console.log("hello2");
    }
```